# Jenkins : How to access build (lastBuild/api/json) details from command line

Tags: jenkins

I have a build setup using jenkins and configured 100+ jobs.
Currently, I have a requirement to get the values of build details from the command line.

From

> jenkins local ip /job/test_3/lastBuild/api/json

I was able to see all the build values, like job name, status, timestamp, etc...

How can one retrieve these values from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

It's a *JSON* API, so you can simply format the URL containing the desired portions of the api, and use *curl* to retrieve the *JSON*.

i.e.

```
http://<server>/job/test_3/lastBuild/api/json
```

To get all 100 of them, you would want to use some sort of script, whether it be *bash* or *Python* or similar so you can put the *curl* command in a loop with the *build number* being the loop index plus one.

*bash* may be the most straightforward if you simply want to execute a bunch of *curl* commands to get the raw *JSON*.

That URL would be of the form:

```
http://<server>/job/test_3/<loopVar + 1>/api/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Ken is correct, use the http requests,
Note that his example will allow you to retrieve the results of all the saved build for one specific job.
If you need to retrieve the status of the last build for each one of the 100+ jobs
I'd suggest the following:
- Retrieve a list of all the jobs in your instance (by calling to  http:///api/json)
- For each job call to /api/json
- find 'lasBuild' field in the resulting object
- call to /json/api to retrieve all the needed info

best done in Python, Perl, Groovy, whatever you feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Execute below command in bash.

** curl -s "hostname/hostIP:port/view/z-admin/job/MSP_PROMOTE/lastBuild/api/json" | python -mjson tool **

- curl curl is a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP). The command is designed to work without user interaction. 
  refer to know more about curl:  (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
- "python -mjson tool" this is python json lib which allow you to see json dump data. After getting json data do grep, cut, paste for what you want sort.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but just wanted to help out people who're still struggling. @khampson's solution is correct but I'll just add a little more to it. To access json API you'll first need to create an API token for the user and use it in the URL that @khampson suggested:

`curl -u admin:<API Token> http://<server IP>:<port>/job/<project name>/lastBuild/api/json`

Use jq to prettify:

`curl -u <username>:<API Token> http://<server IP>:<port>/job/<project name>/lastBuild/api/json | jq`